# Why can't I click on my google map markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, onclick, foursquare, marker

I am having trouble enabling my markers to be clickable.  I have an idea of how to do it, but it won't work.  Below is my javascript.  I tried putting the part I think i have right for the clickable markers. It's mostly on the clickedOn and findRestaurant functions in View Model.  Please let me know if you need anymore info.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My Favorite Restaurants</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- bootstrap CDN: www.getbootstrap.com -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- knockout and app js file -->
        <script src="js/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <!-- google api -->
        <script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB4XqDc-jUpHmSW91uuUHe9TDxXq2GHGYQ&v=3&callback=initMap" onerror="googleMapError()"></script>
        <!-- css files -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- container and row for bootstrap-->
        <div class = "container row">
            <!-- bootstrap column for box-->
            <div class = "options-box col-lg-4 no-float">
                <header>
                    <h1>Restaurants in West LA </h1>
                    <!-- search button-->
                    <form class="form-inline" id="form-search" data-bind="submit: search">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: itemQuery" id="query-input" placeholder="Which Restaurant?" autofocus>
                        <button type="submit" id="submit-button" class="form-control">Search</button>
                    </form>
                    <p id="queryStatus" class = "num-of-restaurants" data-bind="text: getResults"></p>
                </header>
                <!-- adding scroller -->
                <div id="scroller">
                    <!-- list of restaurants -->
                    <ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: {data: restaurantsWanted, as: 'restaurant'}" id="list">
                        <li data-bind="click: $root.clickedOn" class="list-group-item">
                            <span data-bind="text: restaurant.restaurantName" data-toggle="dropdown"></span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <div class="attribution column-md-12"> FourSquare API Source </div>
            </div>
            <!-- map -->
            <div id = "map" class = "col-lg-8 no-float"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

js:

```
   var map;
    // Initializing MAP
    function initMap(){
        var mapAttribute = [
              {
                featureType: 'administrative',
                    elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                    stylers: [{color: '#c9b2a6'}]
                  },
                  {
                    featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
                    elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                    stylers: [{color: '#dcd2be'}]
                  },
                  {
                    featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
                    elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                    stylers: [{color: '#ae9e90'}]
                  },
                  {
                    featureType: 'landscape.natural',
                    elementType: 'geometry',
                    stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
                  }
    ];

    // google map settings
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.0101,-118.4962),
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        styles: mapAttribute,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    ko.applyBindings(new MapAppViewModel());
    }

    // data for functions
    var data;
    var notSelectedIcon;
    var selectedIcon;

    // Functions for Foursquare
    var FSData = function (restaurant, map){
        var self = this;
        self.restaurantName = ko.observable(restaurant.name); self.location = restaurant.location; self.latitude = self.location.lat; self.longitude = self.location.lng;
        // Foursquare Lat and Lng 
        self.MapsLocation = ko.computed(function (){
            if (self.latitude === 0 || self.longitude === 0) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return new google.maps.LatLng(self.latitude, self.longitude);
            }
        });
        self.pinmark = (function (restaurant){
            var pinmark;
            if (restaurant.MapsLocation()){
                pinmark = new google.maps.Marker({ position: restaurant.MapsLocation(), map: map, icon: notSelectedIcon });
            }
            return pinmark;
        })(self);
        self.formattedAddress = ko.observable(self.location.formattedAddress); self.formattedPhone = ko.observable(restaurant.contact.formattedPhone);
        self.id = ko.observable(restaurant.id); self.url = ko.observable(restaurant.url);
        self.WindowInfo = function () {
            return '<div class="selectedWindow">' + 
                '<a href="' + (self.url()===undefined?'/':self.url()) + '">' +
                '<span class="window-header">' + 
                '<h4>' + self.restaurantName() + '</h4>' + 
                '</span>' +'</a>' + 
                '<h6>' + self.formattedAddress()  + '<br>' + self.formattedPhone() + '</h6>' + '</div>';
        };
    };

    // View Model for app
    var MapAppViewModel = function (){
        var self = this;
        notSelectedIcon = markericon('yellow-dot');
        selectedIcon = markericon('red-pushpin');
        function init() {
            findRestaurants();
        }
        var dataInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
        self.restaurantsFound = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.search = function (){
        };
        self.itemQuery = ko.observable('');
        self.getResults = ko.observable('');
        self.restaurantsWanted = ko.computed(function (){
            self.restaurantsFound().forEach(function (restaurant){restaurant.pinmark.setMap(null); });
            var restaurantResults = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.restaurantsFound(), function (restaurant) {
                return restaurant.restaurantName().toLowerCase().includes(self.itemQuery().toLowerCase());
            });
            restaurantResults.forEach(function (restaurant) { restaurant.pinmark.setMap(map); });
            if (restaurantResults.length > 0) {
                self.getResults("Found " + restaurantResults.length + " Restaurants");
                return restaurantResults;
            } else {
                self.getResults("Unable to find restaurants");
                return restaurantResults;
            }
        });
        self.getResults("Looking for Restaurants...");
        **self.clickedOn = function (restaurant){
            restaurant.pinmark.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
            restaurant.pinmark.setIcon(selectedIcon);
            dataInfo.setContent(restaurant.WindowInfo());
            dataInfo.open(map, restaurant.pinmark);
            map.panTo(restaurant.pinmark.position);
            self.restaurantsFound().forEach(function (restaurantNotSelected){
                if (restaurant != restaurantNotSelected) {
                    restaurantNotSelected.pinmark.setAnimation(null);
                    restaurantNotSelected.pinmark.setIcon(notSelectedIcon);
                }
            });
        };**
        // Find Restaurants in Santa Monica
        function findRestaurants(){
            var fourSquareUrl = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search';
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                url: fourSquareUrl,
                data: 'client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&v=20170901%20&ll=34.024212,-118.496475&venuePhotos=1&%20&query=restaurant&limit=6&radius=1000',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function (callback){
                self.restaurantsFound().forEach(
                    **function (restaurant) { if (restaurant.MapsLocation()) {
                            google.maps.event.addListener(restaurant.pinmark, 'click', function () {self.clickedOn(restaurant);});
                    }});**
                infoBack = callback.response.venues;
                infoBack.forEach(function (restaurant) {
                      fsdata = new FSData(restaurant, map); self.restaurantsFound.push(fsdata);
                    }
                ); 
            }).fail(
            // if query cannot be loaded
            function (callback, status, error){ 
              $('#queryStatus').text('Cannot Load Restaurants...');
          });
        }
    }
```

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: What happens when you click a marker? Are there any errors in the console?